# Cypress XHR requests slowdown several tests

Tags: cypress

When I run my test, there are some POST xhr commands that start after my commands (for example after type command) that slowdown my test after some time. I have a for loop of type command (approximately 100 type commands). With each iteration it slows down my test.
Is there a way to solve this?

```
 for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){

  cy.get('tr:has(td)').each(($tr, rowIndex) => {    
    cy.wrap($tr)
      .find('td')                                           
      .then(text => {
        if (text.trim() === '') {          
          cy.wrap($tr).find('td').eq(5).click({force: true}) 
          cy.wait(4000)
cy.get(.model_type).type('Smth') //while typing I'am getting several POST XHR requests that slowdown typing.
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please add your code that you tried to the question.

Comment: So you have say an array of texts and using the for loop you are inputting them?

Comment: I am checking all td and typing there. But the only problem is typing, nothing more

Comment: Will adding a delay in your type help, something like `cy.get(.model_type).type('Smth', {delay: 50})`. So now between every keyrpress there will be a delay of 50 ms.

Comment: You can also use `cy.intercept` to stub the requests before the clicking the button then wait till all the requests are done and then type - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Syntax